How to update a database using a loop?
I'm trying to get my bot to check the database every second, and if someone has 800 XP, to change their rank to 'Elite Genin'.
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as: {bot.user.name}")

    if not loop.is_running():
        loop.start()


@tasks.loop(seconds = 1)
async def loop(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild.id
    table = "PEOPLE_" + str(guild)

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port="3306",
        user="root",
        password="root",
        database="naruto_game"
        )
        cursor = connection.cursor()
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to find name: {}".format(error))
    finally:
        print(f"Logged in as: {bot.user.name}")

    sql_update_query = "UPDATE " + table + "SET rank = 'Elite Genin' where xp = 800"
    cursor.execute(sql_update_query)

But when I run the code, I get this error.
TypeError: loop() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx' 


Why not use the MySQL Event Scheduler for this, rather than a Python loop?

why not passing the ctx, async def loop(ctx):

None of the examples I can find of @tasks.loop have a ctx parameter in the function. What makes you think it's supposed to be defined like that?

@AlwaysSunny They're not calling the function directly, it's called by the nextcord event loop.

@Barmar ohh, i see, thank you sir for pointing it out.

@Barmar I honestly didn't know that was a thing. How would I do something like that?

First hit when googling "Mysql event scheduler": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/event-scheduler.html

Could make an update trigger to change the rank on reaching the level.

This question is similar to: How to create MySQL function to update database if a value reaches 800?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The error is most likely because looping tasks are unable to use ctx directly. ctx in the context of bots (or specifically Discord bots) stands for "context" and means the message a user sends that activates the command. This is often used for commands where you need to know what the user sent, like how much of something to buy from a shop.
However, a looping task is a function that is called in a loop. This means that you can't provide your loop function with any arguments because the loop is calling your function, not you.
For example, say you have a command (function) getXP(ctx) that gets the XP of a user. When a user uses this command using /getXP @thisrandomGuy, the function is called with the message which is the context ctx, a person whose username is "thisrandomGuy", to find that person's XP.
However for a looping task, you can't do that because it repeats a predetermined task. It is NOT called by you.
For your task, the best way to work around this is to loop through your database. When you find an XP amount equal to 800 XP, find the user and the guild/server it's from and send the message.
